# How to apply a Excel formula in VBA macro to find the 2nd to last word

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am quite new to VBA but have been working with Excel a bit. I created a formula that does exactly what I need it to do: find the Nth to last word (mostly 2nd or 3rd to last) in a cell. I think my main issue is how to apply a formula to a range of cells without overwriting the cell and how to use excel formulas in VBA. The Excel formula I use is as follows

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(" "&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",60)),180),60))
```

It might not be the most eloquent way but it works pretty well in Excel. Changing the number 180 to 60 will give last word, 120 2nd to last and so on. But in VBA it gives 1st syntax error and when I get it to run without the arguments and with only TRIM(A1) it overwrites the cell. The code I use is as follows (referencing only A1 to test it):

```
reportsheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(" " & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," " ,REPT(" ",60)),180),60))"
```

My macro searches and extracts specific data from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Now I would want to apply this (or a similar) formula to the data it extracts to the Sheet2. I have tried a lot of different things from using VBA's own trim to making a completely custom function. None of it seems to work and I think it is down to a misunderstanding on how Excel formulas and VBA play together.

In addition I am trying to find a way to find the only numbers in the cell and trim out everything else. Any help with this would also be appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry guys, I had a mistake in the code I provided, it should have been referring to A1 in both instances.

Comment: Try changing the double quotes with single quotes in your VBA formula string.

Comment: your syntax in vba changes. you have to replace " in your normal function by ""', else vba thinks your string is ending and not that you actually want to write down an ". so try this: reportsheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT("" "" & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A20),"" "" ,REPT("" "",60)),180),60))""

Comment: Thank you guys. However, it still overwrites the contents of the cell instead of applying the formula. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: the content of *which* cell? `A20` should be unchanged, `A1` should show the word you extracted.

Comment: I am really sorry, I had a mistake. The code I was testing has A1 in both cases.

Comment: You cannot have two different values in one cell at the same time. How should that work? Either it holds the long string or the extracted word. You will get a *"circular reference"* message from Excel when you do so.

Comment: Yea that was my bad for thinking I could do it. I guess my solution is to trim the string before I move it to the other sheet to avoid having to create 2 sheets

Comment: The common solution is to create a helper column holding the formula. You can even hide it

Answer (score 2):

Double up quotes within a quoted string or use alternatives.

```
reportsheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT("" "" & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A20),"" "" ,REPT("" "",60)),180),60))"
'alternative
reportsheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(char(32) & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A20), char(32), REPT(char(32),60)),180),60))"
```

Answer (score 2):

Doubling the quotes as @Jeeped and the commenters wrote is solving your issue with the formula.
As an alternative, you could write a function ("UDF") that returns the n-th word of a string. It is rather easy by using the VBA function `split` that returns an array of strings. Put the following code in a Module:

```
Public Function getWord(s As String, ByVal n As Integer) As String

    n = n - 1   ' Because Array index will start at 0

    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(s, " ")
    If UBound(arr) >= n Then
        getWord = arr(n)
    End If

End Function
```

In Excel, you write for example `=getWord(A20, 3)` as formula

Comment: Thanks. I mostly work with Excel formulas (sometimes to my own detriment) and am fairly clueless with VBA

Comment: OP wants _n'th to last_ word, so you should return  `arr(UBound(arr) - n + 1)`